# Protractor adds a huge delay after downloading a file while test is running

Tags: file, download, delay, protractor

I'm using Protractor and I'm trying to automate the process of downloading a file from my app to local system. Chrome has been configured to download files without any prompt dialog. The action of downloading a button is a simple click:
**element(by.css("#myDownloadLink")).click();**
This works as expected. However, Protractor adds an unnecessary delay after this action. The download takes a second and the download request is resolved within 1-2 secs. But, Protractor will hang on this line of code for about a min before moving on to the next line - I guess it's syncing unnecessarily or something.

Does anybody have any ideas on how to resolve or at least work around the issue? Like maybe trigger the Download in a different way (but still through the UI?) and avoid the Protractor syncing/hanging

Thanks

Comment: Hi did this got a working fix? other than disabling waitforangular throughout the particular spec

Answer (score 0):

I'd try to play around with `ignoreSynchronization` flag:

```
browser.ignoreSynchronization = true
// trigger download
browser.ignoreSynchronization = false
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried that but it did not work. As soon as you turn ignoreSynchronization back on - it continuities the waiting. Here's the solution:

You have to force angular to do things right away:
    var fixSyncScript = 'var el = document.querySelector("body"); angular.element(el).injector().get("$browser").$$completeOutstandingRequest(angular.noop); return true;';
      browser.executeScript(fixSyncScript).then(function (result) {
        expect(result).toBe(true);
      });