# Delay after downloading a file in Protractor test

Tags: file, download, protractor, delay

My test downloads a file and then clicks a button. The click on the button takes effect (opening a sidebar) 40 secs after. If I disable the downloading code in the app (making the bottom download bar not to appear), the sidebar opens right away without delay.

My question is roughly the same as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29252724/protractor-adds-a-huge-delay-after-downloading-a-file-while-test-is-running). The question has no solution and is quite old, that's why I ask again.

What I have tried:

- reduce timeout with `browser.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(100);`
- `browser.ignoreSynchronization = true;` before downloading (and `browser.ignoreSynchronization = false;` after)
- `await browser.waitForAngularEnabled(false);` before downloading (and `await browser.waitForAngularEnabled(true);` after)
- `browser.executeScript('window.stop();');` after downloading
- `const wins = await browser.driver.getAllWindowHandles(); await browser.switchTo().window(wins[0]);` after downloading
- `await browser.switchTo().activeElement();` after downloading
- `const bd = element(by.css("body")); await browser.actions().mouseMove(bd, { x: 0, y: 0 }).click().perform();` after downloading
- `browser.actions().sendKeys(protractor.Key.ESCAPE).perform();` after downloading
- let ChromeDriver use a Chrome extension to disable bottom download bar (such as [this one](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/disable-download-bar/gjdldigdojpjlmphnogmcmhojfadfmem))

I don't know what is happening, that's why I tried various (and maybe unrelated with the cause) things.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

After searching and trying various things, solved with

```
browser.controlFlow().execute(function () {
    browser.ignoreSynchronization = false;
});
```

before downloading and

```
  browser.controlFlow().execute(function () {
        browser.ignoreSynchronization = true;
    });
```

after.

Can anybody explain me why ?

Comment: If you want an answer to your last question, you may want to ask a new question altogether.